# Visual Studio 2017 intellisense includes full namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Assuming I have two classes called Job and Person with a property called Jobs that is a `List<Job>`. Inside the constructor when I create a new `List<Job>` using intellisense it automatically adds the full namespace `this.Jobs = new List<Demo.Namespace.Job>()`. I just want it to be like this: `this.Jobs = new List<Job>()`. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
public class Job
{

}

public class Person
{

    public Person()
    {
       this.Jobs = new List<Demo.Namespace.Job>() // this should be ... new List<Job>();
    }

    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Maybe you have another class with the same name as `Job` and this is used to getting rid of ambiguity?

Comment: Hmm, my Intellisense gets me to choose between "Demo.Namespace.Job" and "Add 'using Demo.Namespace;' " ... Maybe an Option that can be switched on/off?? Are Job and Person in the same namespace?

Comment: If you add the using directive "using Demo.Namespace" you should be able to use Job without any other qualification of the namespace.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann The point is that VS usually does that automatically for you, rather than prepending the class.

Comment: The wired thing is that they are within same namespace...

Comment: @JamesThorpe It's more semi-automatically since you have to select the option, as OP describes it in one of his comments.

Comment: "they are within same namespace". What is "they"? Job and Person? Doesn't matter, if another "Job" class is also within scope at that moment, you still have to choose. You can't have two "Job" classes within the same namespace, so I assume that's not what you mean.

Comment: @ADyson: I meant that Job and Person are within same namespace so there shouldn't be any confusion. There is no other Job class within the solution.

Comment: There could be one within a library you're referencing, whose namespace is considered active within this file.

Comment: There should be any other class `Job` in namespace you referenced in your file. Try removing the wrong reference or rename your class

Comment: @user2818430, please create a new class and check this issue only happens in this specific class/project or any files.

Comment: I am not sure why people are voting this down.  This is a real annoyance in Visual Studio, and it is not related to using statements.  Just like in the example he provided, the definition and consumption can be in the same namespace, in the same file, and Visual Studio will erroneously add the full namespace *and then immediately yell at you for having unnecessary garbage*.  This happens without ambiguity.  The class can be called XyZlFSofisefoseifOHSOEhfosiG--totally unique--and Visual Studio may force a full namespace declaration, then subsequently yell at you for having it.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of doing that:

1. Add Manuallu an using

   using Demo.Namespace;
   on top of the class
2. Use CTRL+. autocompletion

[image: Picture]

First put the cursor on the object Job and press CTRL+., then pur an using statement with the first menu options (it's the same as point 1).

That will avoid you to have to specify a full namespace every time.

IF YOU ALREADY KNOW THIS, then you have namespace ambiguity.

Try to just put List as you want to do and check what it says in the error window, it will tell you whatever other class is creating ambiguity, then you will have to adapt the namespaces to be different